# Decrypt not Returning Required data in Cryptojs

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, encryption

I want to convert an object to a string and encrypt to make a dynamic url route

After accessing the route I want to decrypt it and convert it back to JSON.

I am using cryptoJS to achieve this but when I attempt to decrypt it returns odd characters such as `�&�j�Ql�8ܐN0m=��r.Z͙R��R�oAë�g_AM�+�����]a�B`

Furthermore, I tried to decrypt it in the file in the file I encrypted it in and got the desired values.

Here is my attempt simplified

Page 1:

```
const encryptedURL = encrypt(JSON.stringify(objectInfo))

<Link to={page2/encryptedURL}
```

Page 2:

```
const { id } = useParams()

 console.log('json', decrypt(id)
//returns �&�j�Ql�8ܐN0m=��r.Z͙R��R�oAë�g_AM�+�����]a�
```

Encryption/Decryption Functions

```
export function encrypt(text) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, SECRET_KEY, IV)

  const encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex')

  return encrypted
}

export function decrypt(hash) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, SECRET_KEY, IV)

  var decrypted = decipher.update(hash, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8')

  return decrypted
}
```

The algorithm is `aes-256-ctr` with key length of 32

Sorry if this is a dumb question I am a complete noob at encryption

Comment: The code is probably not the problem. I rather suspect an inconsistency regarding ciphertext, key,... between encryption and decryption. Compare the data. Btw, you are not using CryptoJS, but the crypto module of NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you I checked my IV key and I am using randomBytes to generate it which create inconsistencies.

Comment: ALERT! Using static IV with the CTR mode is disastrous, could completely reveal the plaintext. IV with the CTR mode must be unique. You can generate random IV or use a counter, then prepend to the ciphertext when encrypting. CTR mode is very malleable, so to be safe, you should use some sort of hmac or other cipher authentication